# Alternative to CASE WHEN to create bins from a column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table where a column (`COL1`) can have values from 0 to 1 (inclusive). From this column I would like to create a new column that categorizes `COL1` using predefined ranges (i.e. create bins). When the number of categories / bins is small, this can easily be done using `CASE WHEN`, for example:

```
SELECT
       CASE WHEN COL1 <= 0.2 THEN 1
            WHEN COL1 > 0.2 AND COL1 <= 0.4 THEN 2
            ....
            WHEN COL1 > 0.8 AND COL1 <= 1 THEN 5
       END AS COL1_bin
FROM   Table
```

Since I would like to have 100 bins, I am looking for a way to do this more 'automatically' using a function, where I can for example give a minimum, maximum and stepsize / binsize (e.g., min = 0, max = 1, stepsize = 0.01)

I am doing this in HiveQL, which is supposed to be very similar to MySQL.

Comment: Create a table `(valueFrom, valueTo, bin_value)` and join it into your query. If the relation is linear you may use simple arithmetic expression instead.

Comment: Isn't that a pure mathmatical mapping? Why not do it in your application instead?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. The answer below by George Joseph works after some slight adaptions (will provide the proposed adaptions and then accept his answer)

Comment: Would love to hear in case you have a simpler / cleaner alternative with simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Hive has a binning function (Postgres does).  But you can use arithmetic:

```
select floor( greatest(least($maxval, col1), $minval) - $minval) /
              $step_size
            ) as bin
from t;
```

If you want the min and maximum values from the data, you can use window functions:

```
select floor( greatest(least(maxval, col1), minval) - minval) /
              $step_size
            ) as bin
from (select t.*,
             min(col1) over () as minval,
             max(col1) over () as maxval
      from t
     ) t;
```

Strictly speaking, you don't need a subquery for the calculation.  But this allows the `bin` to be used for aggregation.

Comment: This seems much faster than the earlier proposed answer, plus it can be implemented probably in any SQL variant. I did a slight adaption to your query: `SELECT  ceil(greatest(col1, 0.01)/0.01) as bin`. This way all values <= 0.01 end up in the first bin. Your solution is probably more general in case the min/max val may differ based on the column, whereas mine is supposed to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here a way to do this. If supposing you would like the bin ranges to be 0.1,0.2,0.3,... till 1. Then you would generate 10 rows using the block row_gen and setting the step_size as row_number/10, and also by setting the lower_limit and upper_limit for each bin.

After that you would need to check if the value for col1 fits in the corresponding lower and upper bound of the bin as follows. (I used left join to include those conditions where the col1 value is null. If this is not a likely scenario then it can be changed to a regular join)

```
with row_gen 
  as (select top 10 
             ,row_number() over(order by 1) as bin_id
             ,row_number() over(order by 1)/10 as as lower_limit
             ,row_number() over(order by 1)/10 + 1/10 as as upper_limit
        from table /*any table that has 10 rows*/ 
      )
   select a.*
          ,b.bin_id
     from your_table a
left join row_gen b
       on a.col1 between b.lower_rnk and b.upper_rnk
```

Comment: Great. Slight adaption was required because the `top` function does not exist in HiveQL apperantly and due to rounding the bins were in some cases slightly incorrect (e.g. 0.199999998 instead of 0.2). Also, I could not perform the join with BETWEEN, so I changed it to a where statement instead. Your query slightly adapted in the next comment

Comment: Edited your answer with the slight adaptions for Hive QL.